# On Apache how to switch off DirectorySlash only for requests to a specific subdomain?

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

Served by Apache I'd like on *one* subdomain site of mine (say `sub.mydomain.com`) that URLs *without* trailing slashes point directly (without external redirect) to the index file in the underlying folder. The subdomain requests are internally redirected to a sub-folder. All other URLS should work in the normal Apache way with external redirect to the slashed version.

All the directives have to go in my .htaccess file. For this to work I am planning to do the following:

1. Switch off `DirectorySlash` for requests to `sub.mydomain.com/...`
2. Rewrite the `sub.mydomain.com/…` requests to `/sub/...`
3. Rewrite slashless directory URLs with  `/sub/...` to fetch the `index.html` inside the underlying directory

I have a good idea how to do 2. and 3., but how can I issue `DirectorySlash off` *only for requests to `sub.mydomain.com`*, but not to `www.mydomain.com` or `other.mydomain.com`?

Comment: Presumably the confusion is that the subdomain `sub` points to the same place as the main domain and all other subdomains?

Comment: @MrWhite The requests to the sub are redirected into the folder /sub. So I only want to switch Directory slash off for everything in that folder. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the sounds of it, your `sub` subdomain maps to the same directory as the main domain and all other subdomains (`www` and `other`, etc.)

However, if all requests to the `sub` subdomain are internally rewritten to the `/sub` *subdirectory* then you can presumably just create another `.htaccess` at `/sub/.htaccess` in which you set `DirectorySlash Off` - this then applies to all requests to the `sub` subdomain. (Assuming you don't also access the same subdirectory via a different hostname. You can prevent this if you wish.)

The `/sub/.htaccess` file is also where you would be implementing #3 in your requirements.

The root `.htaccess` file simply rewrites all requests to the `sub` subdomain to the `/sub` subdirectory.

---

*Aside:* Since you are asking this question on ServerFault it is generally assumed that you have full control of the server. In which case it would be preferable to configure this `sub` subdomain in its own vHost container that points directly to the `/sub` subdirectory (or somewhere outside of the main domains directory tree ideally). In this case, you would not need to implement #2 of your requirements and you just set `DirectorySlash Off` for the entire subdomain.

Comment: It works! As you suggest, the trick is to have a secondary `.htaccess` in the `/sub`. Super cool!